Book Recommendations Similar to Blanchard's Differential Equations
I'm looking for textbooks in Mathematics with the style of Differential Equations by Blanchard, Devaney, and Hall. What I really like about this book is the following:

It is very clear and its explanations are very approachable, which it is great because  it makes complex concepts understandable.
It has a variety of examples, some revisited throughout the book as new topics are introduced.
This is one of my favorite: It has projects that encourage students to go deep into the topics and apply what they’ve learned.

To be honest, I don't know any book similar to the one described, that's why I'm interested in recommendations in any of the following mathematical subjects:

one-variable and multivariable calculus
Linear algebra
Abstract algebra
Topology
Measure theory, and so on.

Any suggestions for books with these characteristics (more applied or theoretical), would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

I'm not familiar with that book, so it's hard for me to endorse something similar.  All of the subjects (to include ODEs) have many many books around.  I would advise surfing the shelves of a college library.  Or even Amazon (you can use the preview feature to look at the foreward and some sample text).  For sure there are texts that are more/less appealing in terms of writing style.  I actually like Schaum's Outlines in general, since they have a simpler (basically lower grade level) text.  I mean just the English writing is less hard to read!

For abstract algebra, I would suggest taking a look at Gallian's book.

Howard Anton's Linear Algebra text has a whole section at the end with projects. If that is what you like about the book then try to find the edition of Anton with the applications at the end.
